# serve static files on nginx: how should I know it works?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

good day.

I have a React application on Red Hat server and I have a  build/static folder on it (there is no index.html file inside, is it normal?). The task is to make nginx to serve static files on this server.

My config is in conf.d in /etc/nginx folder:

```
 $ cat my.conf 
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    root /home/***-user/repo/****/frontend/build/static;
    server_name **.***.***.**;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

I restarted nginx and how should I know that all static files are now served by nginx and are working properly?

Comment: @Ian Kemp Well actually nothing changed for me after I've added this conf. Nothing. If that question is so 'even' so it is simple to answer. What should change? Where should I look? In network or what?

Comment: The index.html file is is the build folder (at the same level the static folder is at).

Answer (score 0):

You should just move in `/home/***-user/repo/****/frontend/build/static` the index.html (with the js,css...) of your React application.

I don't know if your nginx config works, personally I use this one

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {

        root   /../build/static/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
 }
```

Comment: index.html is in        /home/***-user/repo/****/frontend/public      folder and index.js and index.css are in         /home/***-user/repo/****/frontend/src    folder.       Should I move all those 3 files into one  /build/static folder?

Comment: Not necessarily. You just need index.html to be in the folder mentionned in the root attribute in your nginx config

Answer (score 0):

Well, after doing some research it seems that the way to check if nginx work is to go to our site and switch between links on our site while watching over the network tab. In prev version everytime I visited certain tab it downloaded resources, while now it is downloading resources only on 4-5 switching between tabs (And I don't know why, because I set expires to 15 minutes (`expires 15m;` in my conf)

Answer (score 0):

On your browser, visit your https link, open chrome developer tools, and you could see the static files served once you are in root path /.
All the files inside your, /home/***-user/repo/****/frontend/build/static will be served upfront on launching the url.

Comment: well, I can see in the network tab in developer tools https://my_server_address/static/media/some_pic_name.749744ab.svg with the 200 status. And it was the same before enabling nginx.

Comment: Yes. Your app server is serving those static files in your case. There are benefits of serving static assets from nginx proxy server than from your app server. If you haven't enabled nginx, your app server had to serve the static files which is an additional overhead to your server. Where as, nginx is popular for its performance in serving static files, gzip, SSL, and even load-balancing later on.

Comment: Vijay122 but the question still remains: how should I know whether my app server or nginx is doing this?